# Child component's input field not changing with change in parent's props react

Tags: reactjs

I have this ParentComponent with a `<select>` and a ChildComponent with an input field, with its type and value dependent on `props` received. As it is clear in the code, the parent component's `onChangeHandler` updates its state and sends it as prop `data` to child, to which the input field is expected to change. 
I can get the input `type` changed but the input value is not changing, to which I did `value={this.state.input}` which is forcefully getting updated with `componentWillRecieveProps`. Now I am getting the state updated (with a price of `You got me updated again :/` twice), with no change in input value.

Please let me know what I am missing or where I am wrong, and if there is any better way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [selectOpt, setSelectOpt] = useState("")
    const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setSelectOpt(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <select onChange={(e)=>onChangeHandler(e)}>
            <option value="text">text</option>
            <option value="email">email</option>
            <option value="password">password</option>
        </select>
        <ChildComponent data={selectOpt} />
    )
}
class ChildComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        input:this.props.data
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("You got me updated again :/")
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.data !== this.props.data){
            this.setState({ input:nextProps.data })
        }
    }
    render(){
        return( <input type={this.props.data} value={this.state.input} /> )
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask you why are you setting `state.input` in the child component? Looking at your code, it seems you do not really need it, as you are receiving that information from the parent as `prop` and you are not modifying it in any way.

Comment: I saw this attaching value with state as a solution to update the input field, that's why I wrote it to show that I have tried doing that too... But that still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I've been dealing with a similar issue and what helped was setting "key" on a child component. When "key" changes it indicates that component should be refreshed.

You can try this:

`<ChildComponent key={selectOpt} data={selectOpt}/>`

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to put props into its own state, so you should try to avoid that. I don't really know what the prop attribute for the type is, so I am just gonna go with type="text":

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [selectOpt, setSelectOpt] = useState("")
    const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setSelectOpt(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <select onChange={onChangeHandler}>
            <option value="text">text</option>
            <option value="email">email</option>
            <option value="password">password</option>
        </select>
        <ChildComponent data={selectOpt} />
    )
}
const ChildComponent = ({ data }) => {
    return ( 
        <input type="text" value={data} /> 
    )
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to display different `<input>` types, depending on what is selected in the parent component; `ChildComponent` should return `<input type={data} value={data} />` (or, event better, `<input type={data} placeholder={data} />`) rather than `<input type="text" value={data} />`